# Python compiler connected to a button

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

Is it possible to connect the Python compiler to a single button called run? Using PQT4 for Python 3, I have a run button, and a text editor, when the user clicks run I would like all the code in the text editor to be checked and complied. Is this possible? Are there any code examples for something like this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried to run the code in an interactive interpreter instance? [Interactive Console Objects](http://docs.python.org/3/library/code.html#interactive-console-objects)

**Explanation of Interactive console objects**

When you import the class and create a new instance you could then run code without interrupting the main python thread.

```
from code import InteractiveInterpreter

code1 = """
def foo():
    print notDefined

foo()
"""

code2 = """
def baz(spam):
    print spam

baz('eggs')
"""

interpreter = InteractiveInterpreter()
interpreter.runcode(code1)
interpreter.runcode(code2)
```

outputs :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 3, in foo
NameError: global name 'notDefined' is not defined
eggs
```

Comment: you send all the code to the instance and it can give you the results or throw an exception if the code has something wrong

Comment: one second, i will edit the answer to show you a sample

Comment: Thats brilliant, how do i do it so it reads from the text file?

Comment: With the [InteractiveInterpreter.runSource](http://docs.python.org/3/library/code.html#code.InteractiveInterpreter.runsource) method

Comment: Ive tried, interpreter.runsource(self.filname, "signal") as it suggests, but its telling me the filename is not defined

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46935/discussion-between-markcial-and-pro-grammer)