# Embedding IPython console in Tkinter frame

Tags: python, tkinter, ipython

I was working on a PyQt application that had an embedded JupyterWidget that would allow a user to use an IPython console to interact with certain variables that were being displayed. However, it was recently suggested that we switch to Tkinter graphics instead of Qt because of Tkinter's out of the box support in Python.

Is there a Tkinter equivalent implementation of the JupyterWidget in PyQt? The best I can seem to find is https://github.com/ipython/ipython/wiki/Trash:-Old-Embedding-Tkinter but this uses a very old version of IPython where almost all of the function calls are deprecated or removed entirely.

I had also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21811464/how-can-i-embed-a-python-interpreter-frame-in-python-using-tkinter) but was unable to make it so that changes in the subprocess' variables were reflected in the overall program.