# I want to embed IPython console in a tkinter window like spyder IDE does

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, ipython

I am making a code Editor, and I want the logic behind how the developers of spyder IDE implemented IPython in QT window. If you are a spyder developer than please give me the answer or source code of how can I embed IPython console in a Tkinter window.

I had seen the documentation of IPython console https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/reference.html but cannot find a way to do so, and also tried to look at the source code of python interpreter at https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/Lib/idlelib but I am not able to make any logic with it.

```
# main.py
import tkinter as tk
import subprocess
import queue
import os
from threading import Thread

class Console(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.createWidgets()

        # get the path to the console.py file assuming it is in the same folder
        consolePath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"console.py")
        # open the console.py file (replace the path to python with the correct one for your system)
        # e.g. it might be "C:\\Python35\\python"
        self.p = subprocess.Popen(["python3",consolePath],
                              stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                              stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                              stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

        # make queues for keeping stdout and stderr whilst it is transferred between threads
        self.outQueue = queue.Queue()
        self.errQueue = queue.Queue()

        # keep track of where any line that is submitted starts
        self.line_start = 0

        # make the enter key call the self.enter function
        self.ttyText.bind("<Return>",self.enter)

        # a daemon to keep track of the threads so they can stop running
        self.alive = True
        # start the functions that get stdout and stderr in separate threads
        Thread(target=self.readFromProccessOut).start()
        Thread(target=self.readFromProccessErr).start()

        # start the write loop in the main thread
        self.writeLoop()

    def destroy(self):
        "This is the function that is automatically called when the widget is destroyed."
        self.alive=False
        # write exit() to the console in order to stop it running
        self.p.stdin.write("exit()\n".encode())
        self.p.stdin.flush()
        # call the destroy methods to properly destroy widgets
        self.ttyText.destroy()
        tk.Frame.destroy(self)
    def enter(self,e):
       "The <Return> key press handler"
        string = self.ttyText.get(1.0, tk.END)[self.line_start:]
        self.line_start+=len(string)
        self.p.stdin.write(string.encode())
        self.p.stdin.flush()

    def readFromProccessOut(self):
        "To be executed in a separate thread to make read non-blocking"
        while self.alive:
            data = self.p.stdout.raw.read(1024).decode()
            self.outQueue.put(data)

    def readFromProccessErr(self):
        "To be executed in a separate thread to make read non-blocking"
        while self.alive:
            data = self.p.stderr.raw.read(1024).decode()
            self.errQueue.put(data)

    def writeLoop(self):
        "Used to write data from stdout and stderr to the Text widget"
        # if there is anything to write from stdout or stderr, then write it
        if not self.errQueue.empty():
            self.write(self.errQueue.get())
        if not self.outQueue.empty():
            self.write(self.outQueue.get())

        # run this method again after 10ms
        if self.alive:
            self.after(10,self.writeLoop)

    def write(self,string):
        self.ttyText.insert(tk.END, string)
        self.ttyText.see(tk.END)
        self.line_start+=len(string)

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.ttyText = tk.Text(self, wrap=tk.WORD)
        self.ttyText.pack(fill=tk.BOTH,expand=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.config(background="red")
    main_window = Console(root)
    main_window.pack(fill=tk.BOTH,expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

This code is given by Oli or get from [How can I embed a python interpreter frame in python using tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21811464/how-can-i-embed-a-python-interpreter-frame-in-python-using-tkinter)

I want a python 3 code which basically embeds an IPython or Command Prompt in a Tkinter frame or Tkinter text widget or any but Tkinter widget.